How `metadata_ir::RuntimeApiMethodParamMetadataIR` derives `Encode` without deriving `Encode` on `scale_info::MetaType`
I found metadata_ir::RuntimeApiMethodParamMetadataIR derives the parity_scale_codec::Encode, but I didn't find the underlying scale_info::MetaType(T::Type) derive the Encode trait. What did I miss?
https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/d3d1542c1d387408c141f9a1a8168e32435a4be9/substrate/primitives/metadata-ir/src/types.rs#L97

The MetaType is not used when serializing the metadata. PortableType will be used and this implements Encode.
